# How to get nodeName of grandchildren in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a click event on any ( A tag ) to go to the HREF url specified, it works for parent elements but doesn't work for grand children in under the (cmpsocials) class.

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

```
<li class="grid-item" style="cursor:pointer;">
  <div class="elisting-b bus-border">

    <div class="elisting-logo">
        <a class="userlink" href="https://website.com/listing/discountpi">
                                    <img width="307" height="104" src="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/discount-power-inc-logo.png" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/discount-power-inc-logo.png 307w, https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/discount-power-inc-logo-300x102.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 307px) 100vw, 307px"></a>            </div>
    <div class="list-right">
        <div class="companyaddress">
            <h2 class="el-cname"><a class="userlink" href="https://website.com/listing/discountpi">Discount Power Inc.</a></h2>
            <div class="cphone">
                <div class="phn-icon">
                    <a href="tel:(203) 929-3200">(203) 929-3200</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="acdd">6 Armstrong Road, Shelton, NJ 6484, USA
            </div>


            <a class="weblink" href="https://website.com/" target="_blank">https://website.com/</a>
            <div class="cmpsocials">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/website" target="_blank"><img src="https://website.com/wp-content/themes/jobify/images/facebook-icon.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/website" target="_blank"><img src="https://website.com/wp-content/themes/jobify/images/twitter-icon.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/website" target="_blank"><img src="https://website.com/wp-content/themes/jobify/images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/website" target="_blank"><img src="https://website.com/wp-content/themes/jobify/images/youtube-icon.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="two-btn-listing">
            <!--<div class="cmpny-contact"><a href="<? //get_author_posts_url($user->ID, $author_nicename);  ?>">View Listing</a></div>-->
            <div class="sendmsg elisting-btn" auth-id="JGlassman@website.com"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Send a Message</a></div>

            <div class="search-sp">
                <h4>Energy Supply And Distribution</h4>
                <span>energy suppliers</span> </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
jQuery(".grid-item").click(function(e){

    if(child[i].nodeName != "A"){
        window.location=jQuery(this).find("a.userlink").attr("href"); 
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Change `if(child[i].nodeName != "A"){` To `if(this.nodeName != "A"){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
jQuery(".grid-item").click(function(e) {
  if (!jQuery(e.target).is("a")) {
    location.href = jQuery(this).find("a.userlink").attr("href");
  }
});
```

You don't need to use `return false` here as it stops the propagation. Also, you can shorten the finding of event by using `e.target`. This should give you a great start.

Comment: This is close but i do want to stop propagation if (A tag) is found whether in parent or grand children elements. So basically if (A tag) form go to that url and stop everything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".grid-item a.userlink").click(function(e){
   const href = $(this).attr("href");
   // do whatever you need with the href attr value
});
```